# How to run a TypeScript function from the chrome console

Tags: typescript, console

I am using Typescript and want to run a function or set static properties of classes directly via the chrome console to iterate faster. But I don't know how.

I use TypeScript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use Typescript in Chrome. Typescript is superset of JS and you must first compile .TS file to .JS file. If you try use TS in browser, you just get an syntax error.

If you want, you can use extensions for Chrome (for example https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/typescript-console/omklacjbengpcndogglbpjfifmiagmgp), but I do not have any experience with this. I'm pretty sure, that this do not speed up coding.

Comment: // DevTools Console will provide a TypeScript error if you do the following
// Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
let el = document.querySelector(".my-profile.js-gps-track") as HTMLElement
el.click();
// but if you are in the TS Console tab you will be routed to your profile page
// ergo some TypeScript is working with this extension.

Comment: with that said there appears to be no 
    1. history feature on arrow up and down
    2. color syntax
    3. no tab completion nor even tab as spaces (it appears to tab out of the console)
imho these do significantly hamper usage of this chrome extension.